# using routerLinkActive with click event

Tags: angular6, angular-router, angular-routerlink

How can I use `routerLinkActive` with click event and without `routerLink`?
I read somewhere that using click and routerLink together is not a good practice. I want to set an active class when I click the link and want to perform some business functions on click event before navigating the user to the clicked page. The code below is not setting the class.

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
    routerLinkActive="active"
    *ngFor="let service of services"
    (click)="changeService(service)">
    {{ service | titlecase }}
</button>
```